# Styling in JSX using height?

Tags: css, meteor, reactjs

how can i make the jumbotron go down few pixels

```
<div className="jumbotron" style={{height: '-40px'}}>
```

this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use negative values in [`height`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/height/) css property

> Negative values like height: -100px are not accepted.